# Add TikZ node at corner of a tabular cell

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, positioning, tikzmark

I'm trying to place nodes in a tabular to obtain image like this

[image: desired]

I have a command to create an overlay Ti*k*Z node like this

```
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2][]{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[inner sep=0pt,#1](#2){};}
```

My question is: how can I reach corners of cell and add my node without manual adjustment every time I change cell?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2][]{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
 \node[inner sep=0pt,#1](#2){};}  %  yshift=????

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
12  &                            13                           &  32\\
\hline
24  &\tikzmark[xshift=-\tabcolsep]{A}\hfill 14 \hfill\tikzmark[xshift=\tabcolsep]{B}&  45\\
12  &                            13                           &  32\\
\hline
12  &                 very long long long text                &  32
\end{tabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[red](A) to[out=5,in=175](B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Have you considered using the tikz matrix feature to set the table? This will make it easy to get the right coordinates.

Comment: I need to add nodes in a tabular environment not in a tikz matrix

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following example fixes some issues:

- `\coordinate` instead of `\node` for `\tikzmark` avoids additional spacing of a node.
- The default depth of a row in a `tabular` is set to 30 % of the baseline skip and multiplied with `\arraystretch`.

  The example defines the `\RowDepth` outside of the `tabular`, because inside the `tabular`, `\baselineskip` is reset to zero.
- Package `array` is loaded to get a more reliable position of the rules. In a `tabular`, the vertical rules have its own space, if package `array` is loaded. Without the package, the vertical rules are sticking to the left and right cell and might even overprint the cell contents (for ridiculous large rule widths).

Example code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2][]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\coordinate[#1](#2);%
}

\begin{document}

\edef\RowDepth{\the\dimexpr\arraystretch\dimexpr.3\baselineskip\relax\relax}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
12  &  13  &  32  \\
\hline
24  &
  \tikzmark[xshift=-\tabcolsep, yshift=-\RowDepth]{A}%
  \hfill 14\hfill
  \tikzmark[xshift=\tabcolsep, yshift=-\RowDepth]{B}&
  45\\
\hline
12  &  13 &  32\\
\hline
12  &  very long long long text &  32
\end{tabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[red](A) to[out=5,in=175](B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### An alternative approach

The vertical position can be retrieved from a coordinate right below the row:

```
\\% end of the row
\noalign{\tikzmark{C}}% out of alignment, but correct vertical position
```

Then the perpendicular coordinate system can be used to address the start and end points: `(A|-C)` and `(B|-C)`

Full example:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2][]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\coordinate[#1](#2);%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
12  &  13  &  32  \\
\hline
24  &
  \kern-\tabcolsep\tikzmark{A}%
  \hfill 14\hfill
  \tikzmark{B}\kern-\tabcolsep &
  45\\
\noalign{\hbox{\tikzmark{C}}}%
\hline
12  &  13 &  32\\
\hline
12  &  very long long long text &  32
\end{tabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[red](A|-C) to[out=5,in=175](B|-C);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This method deals well with rows, where the depth is not easily known and would have to be measured otherwise.

Comment: Awesome idea  `\noalign{\tikzmark{C}}`  but how can avoid out of alignement ?  why this big space on the right appear ?

Comment: Thanks Heiko Oberdiek  the problem can be solved with `\noalign{\hbox to 0pt{\tikzmark{C}}}`.

Comment: @SalimBou Thanks.`\tikzmark` would start a new paragraph with full line width. Answer updated.

Answer (score 3):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, it's very easy.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}[hvlines-except-borders]
  12 & 13 & 32 \\
  24 & 14 & 45 \\
  12 & 13 & 32\\
  12 & very long long long text & 32
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw [red] (3-|2) to [out=5,in=175] (3-|3) ;
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations.

[image: Output of the first code]

It's also possible to draw the red line before the rules of the tabular (there will be a difference at the extremities of the red line).

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}[hvlines-except-borders]
\CodeBefore
  \tikz \draw [red] (3-|2) to [out=5,in=175] (3-|3) ;
\Body
  12 & 13 & 32 \\
  24 & 14 & 45 \\
  12 & 13 & 32\\
  12 & very long long long text & 32
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code (zoom)]

Comment: Today is easy, but in time of asking this question, this solution  was not available, if I remember correctly :-). Anyway +1 for this nice package

Comment: @Zarko: You are right. In fact, it was not easy to add PGF/Tikz nodes at the corners of the cells of a `{tabular}` and that's why I have written the package `nicematrix` (and it was not very easy to write that package...)