# Diagonal dotted line in table

Tags: tables, tabularx

I currently have the following table: [image]

Which corresponds to the following code:

```
  \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}

\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,marginparwidth=1.5cm]{geometry}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\ra{0.8}
\centering
\caption{bla }
\begin{tablenotes}
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1}
\small
    \item Note: bla.   
\end{tablenotes}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}
\begin{tabular}{l | c | c c c c }
\toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Panel A: Countries}\\
   \hline
 & Average & Netherlands &  Germany & France & Belgium  \\ \hline
Netherlands & 3.83 &  &  &  &    \\
Germany  & 3.87 &  &  &  &    \\
France  & 3.95 &  &  &  &    \\
Belgium  & 3.91 &  &  &  &    \\
\midrule
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Panel B: Clients}\\
   \hline
 & Average & Advisory &  Execution Only &  &   \\\hline
Advisory & 3.86 &  &  &  &    \\
Execution Only & 3.78 &  &    &  &  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\label{tab:VarImportc}

\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

I would like to include two diagonal dashed lines on the right hand sides of both panels (i.e. from Netherlands-Netherlands to Belgium-Belgium and Advisory-Advisory to Exec-Exec).

Also, I was wondering how I can make the first column (Average) distinct from the RHS of the table? I now did it via vertical lines, but it doesn't look very nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, your code had some minor errors. 
Secondly, your questions are not clear to me! BTW, as far as I noticed from your text, I will do it with the aid of `tikz` package. see the following code:

```
  \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}

\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,marginparwidth=1.5cm]{geometry}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}


\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\noindent\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
%\ra{0.8}
\centering
\caption{bla }
\begin{tablenotes}
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1}
\small
    \item Note: bla.   
\end{tablenotes}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}
\begin{tabular}{l || c || c c c c }
\toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Panel A: Countries}\\
   \hline
 & Average & Netherlands &  Germany & France & Belgium  \\ \hline
Netherlands & 3.83 & \tikzmark{start}\phantom{Netherlands} &  &  &    \\
Germany  & 3.87 &  &  &  &    \\
France  & 3.95 &  &  &  &    \\
Belgium  & 3.91 &  &  &  &  \phantom{Belgium}\tikzmark{end}   \\
\midrule
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Panel B: Clients}\\
   \hline
 & Average & Advisory &  Execution Only &  &   \\\hline
Advisory & 3.86 &  &  &  &    \\
Execution Only & 3.78 &  &    &  &  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\label{tab:VarImportc}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw [dashed] (start.north) -- (end.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps a dumb question: when I try to do the same for the lower panel, the diagonal line for panel A disappears. I added \tikzmark{start}\phantom{Advisory} and \phantom{Execution Only}\tikzmark{end}. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You will need to give the coordinates different names, e.g. `\tikzmark{start2}\phantom{Advisory}` and `\tikzmark{end2}\phantom{Execution Only}`, and then draw another dashed line further down, `\draw[dashed] (start2.north) -- (end2.south);`

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by placing a tikz coordinate in the relevant cells, using `remember picture` and `overlay` to then let you go back and draw lines after creating the table. For example (I've cut down your example to a MWE -- note that you are currently calling the `threeparttable` package twice, which you'll want to fix):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}
\begin{tabular}{l | c | c c c c }
\toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Panel A: Countries}\\
   \hline
 & Average & Netherlands &  Germany & France & Belgium  \\ \hline
Netherlands & 3.83 & \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\coordinate(Netherlands);} &  &  &    \\
Germany  & 3.87 &  &  &  &    \\
France  & 3.95 &  &  &  &    \\
Belgium  & 3.91 &  &  &  &  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\coordinate(Belgium);}  \\
\midrule
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Panel B: Clients}\\
   \hline
 & Average & Advisory &  Execution Only &  &   \\\hline
Advisory & 3.86 & \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\coordinate(Advisory);} &  &  &    \\
Execution Only & 3.78 &  &  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\coordinate(Exec);}  &  &  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[dashed](Netherlands) -- (Belgium);
\draw[dashed](Advisory) -- (Exec);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This draws a dashed line from teh centre of the corresponding cells. You can move the start/finish points by specifying an `xshift` and/or `yshift` parameter in the `\coordinate` commands, for example:

```
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\coordinate[xshift=20pt](Netherlands);}
```

This answer is based on similar work done here: [Add TikZ node at corner of a tabular cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349045/add-tikz-node-at-corner-of-a-tabular-cell)

Answer (score 2):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` is similar to the classical environment `{tabular}` (of the package `array`) but creates PGF/TikZ nodes under the cells, columns and rows. Then it's possible, in the so-called `\CodeAfter` to use TikZ to draw whatever rule you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,marginparwidth=1.5cm]{geometry}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]

\centering
\caption{my caption }
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{l | c | c c c c }
    \toprule
    \Block[l]{1-*}{\bfseries Panel A: Countries} \\ \hline
     & Average & Netherlands &  Germany & France & Belgium  \\ \hline
    Netherlands & 3.83 &  &  &  & \\
    Germany  & 3.87 &  &  &  & \\
    France  & 3.95 &  &  &  & \\
    Belgium  & 3.91 &  &  &  & \\
    \midrule
    \Block[l]{1-*}{\bfseries Panel B: Clients} \\ \hline
     & Average & Advisory &  Execution Only &  & \\ \hline
    Advisory & 3.86 &  &  &  & \\
    Execution Only & 3.78 &  & &  &  \\
    \bottomrule
\CodeAfter
    \tikz \draw [dotted] (3-|3) -- (7-|7) (9-|3) -- (11-|7) ; 
\end{NiceTabular}\label{tab:VarImportc}

\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because of the PGF/TikZ nodes used by `nicematrix`).

[image: Output of the above code]